# Update of an entity with ttl not working as expected with Datastax Java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to add ttl to an existing record(at the entity level and not column) which gets saved in a batch, there is an enum in that table which gets updated and ttl is applied whenever customer chooses that option, but what I see is after the ttl period expires the row doesn't get deleted and only the enum is back to what it was before applying the ttl. The code looks something like below where customer is the entity being persisted, ttl is a transient Integer field which gets set > 0 only on updates while customerMapper is the Mapper< Customer>

```java
            if(customer.getTtl() > 0) {
                batchStatement.add(customerMapper.saveQuery(customer, ttl(customer.getTtl())));
            } else {
                batchStatement.add(customerMapper.saveQuery(customer));
            }
```

the table_schema:

```
        CREATE TABLE customer (
            id uuid,
            tenant_id bigint,
            workspace_id bigint,
            creation_date timestamp,
            in_control_group boolean,
            monitored boolean,
            num_sessions int,
            id_status tinyint,
            recognized boolean,
            PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id, workspace_id)
            );
```

We're using Cassandra 3+, The table has a read and write consistency set to LOCAL_QUORUM while the compaction is Level_Tiered. Any thoughts on what probably is wrong?

Comment: please post table schema & code for your POJO

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, thanks for your response, I've edited my post with the schema above, what specifically do you need for the POJO, just the entity design(Primary Key and Clustering Key) or something else?

Comment: I suspect that you either insert new row (that's why I'm asking about primary key), or your overwrites aren't propagated correctly, like, no repair running - that could explain data resurrection

Comment: @AlexOtt, id is the partitionKey while tenant_id and workspace_id are the clustering column, I'm updating the entity only on non-primary columns and when I run SELECT on cqlsh, there's just one row on that primary key, so pretty sure no new row is being added, not sure about the repair though, it'll be really helpful if you could provide insights on that.

Comment: Check that clocks are synchronized on client as well

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that next, but the ttl is working fine for other tables, i.e when an update is done, ttl is applied to the entries in 3 tables, 2 are working fine, it's just this one table

Comment: @AlexOtt, I figured out the problem here, so what was happening was, the insert query was saving 3 columns: creation_date, in_control_group and recognized in addition to PK while then the update query didn't comprise creation_date and in_control_group as we're not really updating those columns. Setting those two explicitly in addition to our current mutator logic worked for me.